# Your own view in django sphinxdoc

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am using django **sphinxdoc**. I want to have my own view so that I can use `@login_required` decorator with sphinx. Please give an idea how to create such view. As far as I've been researching, sphinxdoc is rendered by `documentation()` function from `sphinxdoc.views`:

```
import datetime
import json
import os.path

from django.conf import settings
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.static import serve
from haystack.views import SearchView

from sphinxdoc.forms import ProjectSearchForm
from sphinxdoc.models import Project, Document


BUILDDIR = os.path.join('_build', 'json')
CACHE_MINUTES = getattr(settings, 'SPHINXDOC_CACHE_MINUTES', 5)


@cache_page(60 * CACHE_MINUTES)
def documentation(request, slug, path):
    """Displays the contents of a :class:`sphinxdoc.models.Document`.

    ``slug`` specifies the project, the document belongs to, ``path`` is the
    path to the original JSON file relative to the builddir and without the
    file extension. ``path`` may also be a directory, so this view checks if
    ``path/index`` exists, before trying to load ``path`` directly.

    """
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
    path = path.rstrip('/')

    try:
        index = 'index' if path == '' else '%s/index' % path
        doc = Document.objects.get(project=project, path=index)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        doc = get_object_or_404(Document, project=project, path=path)

    # genindex and modindex get a special template
    templates = (
        'sphinxdoc/%s.html' % os.path.basename(path),
        'sphinxdoc/documentation.html',
    )

    try:
        env = json.load(open(os.path.join(project.path, BUILDDIR,
                                          'globalcontext.json'), 'rb'))
    except IOError:
        # It is possible that file does not exist anymore (for example, because
        # make clean to prepare for running make again), we do not want to
        # display an error to the user in this case
        env = None

    try:
        update_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(
            os.path.join(project.path, BUILDDIR, 'last_build')))
    except OSError:
        # It is possible that file does not exist anymore (for example, because
        # make clean to prepare for running make again), we do not want to
        # display an error to the user in this case
        update_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)

    data = {
        'project': project,
        'doc': json.loads(doc.content),
        'env': env,
        'update_date': update_date,
        'search': urlresolvers.reverse('doc-search', kwargs={'slug': slug}),
    }

    return render_to_response(templates, data,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The function `documentation()` is called by below URL from `sphinxdoc.urls`:

```
url(
    r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    'documentation',
    {'path': ''},
    name='doc-index',
),
```

So what is the right way to build required view in some app so that sphinx documents were rendered not by `sphinxdoc.views`, but my own view?